# Jquery Datepicker no me coje el formato de fecha en español

Tags: html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui, html-select

Tengo este código con Jquery para mostrar dos datepicker y cuando hago click en el me muestra la fecha bien, pero al mostrarla en el input me la muestra en formato "m-d-y"

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <input id="dp_start" width="276" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    <input id="dp_end" width="276" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#dp_start').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        language: 'es',
        locale: 'es-es',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        startDate: '-3d',

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        },
        onChange: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        }
    });

    $('#dp_end').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        language: 'es',
        locale: 'es-es',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

        changeDate: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        }
    });
    );
</script>
```

Os muestro unas imagenes del comportamiento.

Paso 1- Hacer click encima del datepicker
[image: el datepicker]

Paso 2 - Una vez he hecho click en una fecha del datepicker

[image: una fecha seleccionada en el datepicker]

Tal como explico, intento seleccionar el dia 4 de Enero del 2020 y me acaba poniendo el 1 de Abril del 2020.

Comment: si dejas solo dateformat y uilibrary a mí me funciona así que el fallo está en otro lugar, prueba con https://gijgo.com/LiveEdit/Index/bootstrap-4.html?component=datepicker#

Comment: ¿Qué librería estás usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta cambiando dateFormat por **format**

```
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

En el DatePicker de bootstrap4 se utiliza el atributo **format** dado que *formatDate* está obsoleto en esta versión.

Saludos.

Comment: solo con dateformat me funciona así que ahí no está el problema

Comment: En el DatePicker de bootstrap4 se utiliza el atributo format. formatDate está obsoleto.

Comment: mira la web que he propuesto, y haz pruebas, no cambiando dateFormat me da bien eliminando locale, y los eventos, otra cosa es la buena o mala practica

Comment: gracias Nicolas...pues es verdad he modificado dateFormat por Format y funcion a la 1º.

Comment: De nada, voy a agregar esta aclaración en la respuesta para que quede documentado.